# Single mouse click turns into drag and drop when connecting to remote devices

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, remote-desktop, mouse-gestures

On Ubuntu 20.04, I have a strange problem which is that regular mouse clicks turn into press and hold, drag and drop icon events when connected to a remote mobile device. The strange thing is that this happens both when using dedicated software (scrcpy) as well as a browser-based client connection (in firefox). This makes me think it's not the specific software or service that is to blame, but something in my ubuntu configutation. I guess the remote connections are too slow which causes the regular mouse click to be misinterpreted. But is there some way to temporarily disable click-and-hold behavior? Ie make every mouse click last for say 1ms only. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What software are you using the remotely connect?

Comment: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy as well as Firefox (web-based client).